# How do I reflect back the name of a Type supplied as a generic?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, reflection

How to I reflect back the name of a type that is supplied as a generic parameter?  I would really like to know how this is done in both C# and VB.NET.  See the following example code and expected response.

In C#:

```
public void Test<T>()
{
     Console.WriteLine("The supplied type is {0}",???)
}
```

In VB.NET

```
Public Sub Test(Of T)()
     Console.WriteLine("The supplied type is {0}",???)
End Sub
```

Executing `Test<String>()` or `Test(Of String)()` should produce:

```
The supplied type is String
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C# ([typeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs(VS.71).aspx) operator):

```
public void Test<T>()
{
    Console.WriteLine("The supplied type is {0}", typeof(T));
}
```

VB.NET ([GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tay4kywk(VS.71).aspx) operator):

```
Public Sub Test(Of T)()
    Console.WriteLine("The supplied type is {0}", GetType(T))
End Sub
```

---

C#'s `typeof(T)` and VB.NET's `GetType(T)` return a `System.Type` object that has properties and methods for retrieving information about a specific `Type`.  By default, `System.Type`'s `.ToString()` method will return the fully qualified name of the Type.  To return only the `Name` of the type, call `typeof(T).Name` or `GetType(T).Name` in C# or VB.NET, respectively.

Comment: thanks for the answer!  That helped me get started.  I added some additional information around `System.Type` so that others know that it's actually a first-class Object with properties and methods.  Feel free to edit it out if I added anything incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

[Darin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161101/how-do-i-reflect-back-the-name-of-a-type-supplied-as-a-generic/3161109#3161109)'s answer is correct, but it's also worth noting that if you receive an instance of `T` as a parameter you can use `.GetType()` as well:

```
public void Test<T>(T target)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The supplied type is {0}", target.GetType());
}
```

Just a different approach (`typeof` will inspect the *type argument* whereas `.GetType()` works with *an instance of the type*).

---

As Daniel notes in the comments there is a nuance to consider:  `typeof(T)` will return the type-argument's Type, whereas `.GetType()` will return the exact type of the object--which may *inherit* from `T`, and `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(target.GetType())` may return true--but the specific concrete types may differ.

An example:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      GenericClass<TypeX>.GenericMethod(new TypeX());
      GenericClass<TypeX>.GenericMethod(new TypeY());
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }

  public class TypeX {}

  public class TypeY : TypeX {}

  public static class GenericClass<T>
  {
    public static void GenericMethod(T target)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("TypeOf T: " + typeof(T).FullName);
      Console.WriteLine("Target Type: " + target.GetType().FullName);
      Console.WriteLine("T IsAssignable From Target Type: " + typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(target.GetType()));
    }
  }
}
```

Resulting output:

Passing in an instance of ***TypeX*** as the parameter:
TypeOf T: ConsoleApplication2.***TypeX***
Target Type: ConsoleApplication2.***TypeX***
T IsAssignable From Target Type: True

Passing in an instance of ***TypeY*** as the parameter:
TypeOf T: ConsoleApplication2.***TypeX***
Target Type: ConsoleApplication2.***TypeY***
T IsAssignable From Target Type: True

Comment: Note that `typeof(T)` will return the specified type argument while `target.GetType()` will return the actual type of the supplied argument - this can be `T` but also every sub-type of `T`. Further `target.GetType()` may cause a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I don't think this answer deserves negative points. He explains just fine what is going on with the different approach, and this approach can be a valid thing to do. It should be obvious that calling GetType() can lead to a null ref exception as well, not worth mentioning really.

Comment: Daniel's right... though I'm not sure why an answer that provides useful info would receive a downvote...

Comment: I absolutely agree, it is a valid and helpful answer (and I neither up nor down voted it in the case someone understands my comment as critique).

Comment: @Daniel -- good point, I updated (and probably overcomplicated) my answer to point out the nuance :D